# What trade should I hire to vent a microwave through my roof?

Tags: hvac

Putting in a new kitchen and I cant vent microwave vent directly outside because roof eave in way Need to go up thru roof What subtrade can I use to vent a microwave thru attic

Comment: Either a handyperson or an HVAC contractor.

Comment: Counter-top microwave ovens are not usually vented to the outside and they don't inject excessive water vapor or cooking smells into the interior living space. Why do you want to go to the trouble and expense of venting one to the outside?

Comment: Who said anything about a countertop unit? I assumed a range hood unit.

Comment: The question referred to venting a microwave oven so I assumed (possibly wrongly I now realize) that the vent was *only* for a microwave oven. Perhaps the OP *was* thinking about venting for a range with the complication of a microwave oven right where the range hood would be. Personally I like the space above the range to be clear. The bottom of our vent hood is 29" above the surface burners of the range.

Answer (score 2):

Some microwaves come with an optional "vent to exterior" feature. We require a vent when installed over cooktop or oven. It comes with a charcoal filter that recirculates the air, but a small steel "flap" can be removed in the back and hooked up to duckwork and extended to exterior...it doesn't need to go through roof...whichever is easiest. Make sure it has a "backdraft" flap.

I'd use a carpenter/handyman. Get a bid, make sure their licensed and ask for references.

Comment: "duckwork" ... ?

Comment: Darn autocorrect...

Comment: I quack understand and agree.

Answer (score 0):

I vented our Samsung microwave in our old home, at 300CFM you can definitely minimize the remaining odors from food. We have since moved out of that home and are about to remodel the kitchen in our new home, and we will 100% look to do the same. Check the side of the vent opening on your microwave, but a hood vent boot, and then however much tubing you need to run it out. As someone else has said, a handyman, or even some plumbers can vent it outside for you.